# riemann.io add jar to classpath

Tags: jar, clojure, classpath, leiningen, riemann

I have written custom clojure functions that I want to use in my riemann configuration. I am using leiningen to build jar file (with dependencies) containing my functions. What is the right way to include this jar file in the classpath when starting riemann ?

Comment: https://github.com/pyr/riemann-extra#configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only found this way. I'm not sure whether this is the right way :

java -cp "/path/to/my/custom.jar:/path/to/riemann-0.2.6/lib/riemann.jar" riemann.bin /path/to/riemann-0.2.6/etc/riemann.config