# How can I use clj-http in riemann.config

Tags: clojure, riemann

I use riemann and now I write my `riemann.config`.

I want to use `clj-http` post all events from riemann stream to my web server. But I don't know how to import `clj-http` from riemann.jar.

I code `(:use clj-http.client)` or `(:require [clj-http.client :as client])`  in `riemann.config` but got error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clj-http.client
```

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: I had similar question some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766730/riemann-io-add-jar-to-classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar few months ago and this was working for me. I was using http-kit :

```
(require '[org.httpkit.client :as http])
```

Since both http-kit and cli-http are available in riemann ( see https://github.com/aphyr/riemann/blob/master/project.clj ) You should be able to require cli-http the same way :

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as client])
```

Problem in your configuration is that you are using (:use ... an (:require .... which is supposed to be used within the namespace declaration. Since riemann.config doesn't contain namespace declaration you can't use these forms. When calling

```
(:use clj-http.client)
```

you get ClassNotFoundException because clojure is trying to invoke function :use on clj-http.client , which can't be found. Outside the namespace declaration :use is just a standard keyword with no special meaning.